# Is it possible to add a video call feature on an app using Smartface App Studio?

Tags: smartface.io

Is it possible to add a video call feature on an app using Smartface App Studio?

I've tried cloning Viber using another software however it wasn't successful

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No; 
Long answer: Maybe
Smartface doesn't have direct support for SIP/VoIP. For video you could use Sockets (however the problem still remains on video encoding). 
However, to implement a video call feature I would recommend to do this using the native platform SDKs